# JS - make dynamic url from all array data (array length is not fixed)

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, dynamic-url

I am trying to make a dynamic url from all array data.
Now I have come to this part and I don't have idea how to resolve this.
Can You please help?

```
    //Get image
    function get_image(img_arg){

        var length = img_arg.length;

        for (x = 0; x < length; x++){

            //I would like to make url like this:
            //var url = img_arg[0] + '-' + img_arg[1] + '-' + img_arg[2]...till the max;
        }


        console.log(url);
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `join()` function on your array and pass `-` as parameter. It concatenates all items with passed parameter and returns you a string.

As an example you can see

```js
var img_arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
var arr = img_arr.join('-');

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Thank You, that was the answer that I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding a little to your code:

```
//Get image
function get_image(img_arg) {
    var img_url = "";

    for(x=0; x<img_arg.length; x++) {
        img_url += img_arg[x] + '-';
    }

    img_url = img_url.substring(0, img_url.length-1);
    console.log(img_url);
}
```

Comment: If I use slice than I lose first letter of array instead of last. Therefore I have tried like this and it works:    function get_image(img_arg) {
   console.log(img_arg);

      var img_url = "";

      for(x=0; x<img_arg.length; x++) {


       if(x == img_arg.length-1){

        img_url += img_arg[x];

       } else {

           img_url += img_arg[x] + '-';
        
       }


      }

      console.log(img_url);
  }

Comment: @BotićDenis Your solution works, but personally, I'd rather "trim the last character at the end" rather than "test if it's the last item on each iteration"...  In that case, you're evaluating `img_arg.length` extra conditions, instead of just 1 call to substring()...

If your img_arg has thousands of items, it could cause slowness in the browser.

Comment: I see, You are right. I also needed this example and thank You for explaining this.